# Populating listview row into an array or list

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listview

Is it possible to enter listview data by row instead of by cell?  I would like to be able to pull data out of the listview by row using an index rather than having to create a ton of statements to pull out the data by cell, it would be easier this way.

Comment: Have you looked into a DataGridView?

Comment: Yeah, the DataGridView can be customized to look almost exactly like a ListView

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The issue isn't with the LIstview or the functionality of the listview, is there a way to grab the whole row full of data and put it into a list or array?

Comment: no.  that why they are suggesting a DGV